# Filtering out abnormal connection termination packets in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to find out a way to filter out packets specifying abnormal connection termination in wireshark. I mean is there any tcp.connection.terminated filter in wireshark??

Comment: An abnormal TCP connection termination is a RST, so you can filter for that.

Comment: you mean tcp.connection.rst??

Comment: Would you please also tell me whether normal termination is FIN??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP FIN is a normal termination.

Abnormal connection terminations would have TCP RST flag enabled: `tcp.flags.reset == 1`

A connection can also time out (keepalive SYN is sent more than once, no ACK received back).

You can filter for the TCP SYN flag using display filter `tcp.flags eq 0x02` and look for connections that do not receive ACK.